# If statement in python working different just by changing position of condition

Tags: python, c++, mergesort

I just encountered a weird problem in python:
below is an implemntation of the merge sort algorithm that gives me an index error if I try to run it.

```py
def mergesort(s1,s2,S):
    i,j = 0,0
    while i+j < len(s1)+len(s2):
        if (i < len(s1) and s1[i] < s2[j]) or j == len(s2):
            S.append(s1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            S.append(s2[j])
            j += 1
    return S

s2 = [1,5,7]
s1 = [2,3,4,6,8]
S = []
print(mergesort(s1,s2,S))
```

Output of this program is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(mergesort(s1,s2,S))
  File "new.py", line 4, in mergesort
    if (i < len(s1) and s1[i] < s2[j]) or j == len(s2):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and now just by typing `j == len(s2)` before, in the `if` statement, the program runs perfectly fine:

```py
def mergesort(s1,s2,S):
    i,j = 0,0
    while i+j < len(s1)+len(s2):
        if j == len(s2) or (i < len(s1) and s1[i] < s2[j]):
            S.append(s1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            S.append(s2[j])
            j += 1
    return S

s2 = [1,5,7]
s1 = [2,3,4,6,8]
S = []
print(mergesort(s1,s2,S))
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

This is really surprising to me as both the programs are exactly the same but the former one gives me an error.

Furthermore, the offending program runs fine in c++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int s1[10] = { 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 }, s2[10] = { 1, 5, 7 }, s[20], i = 0, j = 0, x = 0;
    while (i + j < 8) {
        if ((i < 5 && s1[i] < s2[j]) || j == 3) {
            s[x++] = s1[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            s[x++] = s2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << s[i];
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Output: `12345678`

and why does the program that was giving me an error in python run perfectly fine in c++?
does the `if` statement of python work differently than the `if` statement of c++?

Comment: The first code evaluates `s1[i]<s2[j]`. The second doesn't. In the third code you are witnessing undefined behavior.

Comment: Then why does the program runs perfectly fine in c++?

Comment: Because in C++ accessing out of bounds doesn't have to crash the program. This form of undefined behavior is the worst. It looks like your code is correct but it's not.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub - Undefined Behaviour is *undefined*. The compiler is not obligated to do *anything* in particular once you break the language rules. *Anything* is ok - including crashing, doing nothing, looping forever, doing what you intended, emailing your porn collection to your mother or *anything* else.

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility. C++ offers great power. Its programmers are expected to be responsible.

Comment: That's not weird behavior in Python. Your first code and your third code are wrong. In Python you get diagnostics. In C++ you can get weird behavior from time to time. In Python you are getting the error message `IndexError: list index out of range`. In C++ you are accessing random memory values. Your program could crash. Your results could be wrong. You can't be sure what will happen.

Comment: Okay well I already knew that in the first code the condition isn't evaluated but I jusr wanted to know why it worked in c++ and python , thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first python program is indeed incorrect: `if (i < len(s1) and s1[i] < s2[j]) or j == len(s2):` will cause an out of bounds access to `s2[j]` if `j` reaches the length of `s2` before `i` reaches the end of `s1`.

The fix is to test for `j == len(s2)` **before** `(i < len(s1) and s1[i] < s2[j])` as you correctly found out yourself.

The C++ program has the same problem but C++ does not detect out of bounds accesses. Reading `s2[3]` simply has undefined behavior and in your case just returns an unspecified value. The test will evaluate to true anyway because `j == 3`, so the algorithm outputs the expected result.

Undefined behavior can sometimes produce the expected result and go unnoticed. But using the algorithm on larger allocated arrays could produce a visible side effect such as a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and properly editing my question because it contained grammatical mistakes.